# Custom marker based on geojson attribute in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, filter, markers, icon

I would like to customize a marker to add an id (number) on top of it, this id is coming from an attribute of the geojson ("id" in the following example)

```
{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "id":1,
        "destination":"Police station",
        "coordinates":[
          "4.3520735404177699","50.846502697562201"
        ]
      },
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "id":2,
        "destination":"Museum",
        "coordinates":[
          "4.347903728485107","50.846658450225334"
        ]
      },
...
```

I'm stuck with L.ExtraMarkers :

```
var json = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
            icon: 'fa-number',
            number: 'x',
            iconColor: 'white',
            markerColor: 'black',
            shape: 'circle',
            prefix: 'fa'
            });

    var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("query_json.php?&do=DCT1",{pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: json});    
    },

    onEachFeature: function (feature,layer) {
        var popup = [];
        for (var prop in feature.properties) {
            popup.push(prop + ": " + feature.properties[prop]);
        }
        layer.bindPopup(popup.join("<br />"));
    }}).addTo(map);
```

**number: 'x',** should be the variable "id" coming from the geojson.

I'm also stuck with L.circleMarker :

```
var stylegeojson = {color:'white', fillColor:'blue', radius:10, opacity:1.0, fillOpacity:1.0, weight:2};

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("query_json.php?&do=DCT1", {pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, stylegeojson);
                // what should I add here to print "id" value on top of it ?
    },
    }).addTo(map);
```

I think I have to add an

> onEachFeature: function(feature, id) {

but I don't know to write it.

Ideally I'd also like to have a different marker color per "destination"

I am wondering if someone already did this before or has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, your GeoJSON is invalid. Each feature should have a `geometry` and a `properties` property. i.e. the following is wrong:

```
var feature = {
  "type":"Feature",
  "geometry":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[ "4.347903728485107","50.846658450225334" ],
    "id":2,
    "destination":"Museum"
  }
}
```

And the following is right:

```
var feature = {
  "type":"Feature",
  "geometry":{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[ "4.347903728485107","50.846658450225334" ]
  }, 
  "properties": {
    "id":2,
    "destination":"Museum"
  }
}
```

Use [GeoJSONLint](http://geojsonlint.com/) to check validity of your GeoJSON.

Second: the `pointToLayer` function should refer to the value of the `id` property of the feature if you want to use it.

This is wrong:

```
var icon= L.icon.glyph({
  prefix: '',
  glyph: feature.properties.id,
  // Any other icon options here
});

var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(featureCollection, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: icon})
  }
});
```

And this is right (note the [variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variable_scope) for `feature` and thus `feature.properties.id`:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJSON(featureCollection, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: L.icon.glyph({
        prefix: '',
        glyph: feature.properties.id
      })
    })
  }
})
```

See a [working example](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/divu/edit?html,output) using [Leaflet.Icon.Glyph](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Icon.Glyph).

> I think I have to add an `onEachFeature: function(feature, id) {`

No, you don't. If you want to create a different marker for each GeoJSON point feature, do so in the `pointToLayer` callback option. Use `onEachFeature` for stuff you want to get done **after** the leaflet layers (markers/lines/polygons) have been instantiated.

Comment: Thank you for this pedagogic answer, it worked directly. Solved for me !

Comment: The 'id' property should be a [top-level property on Feature](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.2), rather than a member of 'properties'.